# Convert List<object> to List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, casting

After I de-serialize some Json data I get a data structure, the type being `List<object>` (I checked that using `GetType()`).

However this data structure was originally a `List<List<int>>` when I first serialized it. 
So to get it back as a `List<List<int>>` I did:

```
List<object> LObj = jsonArray[0] as List<object>;
List<List<int>> result = LObj.Cast<List<int>>.ToList();
```

However I get a `InvalidCastException` in the `ToList()` call.

Is this possible at all, or Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How are you deserializing it?

Comment: @Rob using NewtonSoft Json library

Comment: Well yes; but I mean - can we see your code? You can specify the structure you want it deserialized as (which, if specified correctly, will fix your issue)

Comment: Basically I just posted part of the problem here my original data structure was a array with many slots 1 of which being `List<List<int>>` and  it was serialized to json  on another platform (AS3), and you are right it seems I making a mess of the data in my code itself after I deserialize it with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)` I seem to be passing the result through some custom code that loops thru it and converts it to List<object> probably not the best way of doing it

Comment: Are you able to simply do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<int>>>(json)`?

Comment: I could probably do that however since my json data was an array with assorted slots. I mean some slots have List<List<int>> some have List<int> some have List<object> so how do I deserialize only one slot from a json string, using your line of code?

Answer (score 0):

It's Boxing and Unboxing
try to do something like that:

```
        List<object> LObj = new List<object>();
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

        foreach (var item in LObj)
        {
            int i = (int)item;
            myList.Add(i);
        }

        result.Add(myList);
```

more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing